# Deprecated: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::connect() should not be called statically

Tags: smarty, php-7, smarty3

I am using SmartyPaginate plugin for SMARTY Template and its throwing 6-7 errors of same type from this very plugin. All error came up when I upgraded to PHP 7. Although I can disable error showing but I would really like to resolve that permanently.

Deprecated: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex() should not be called statically in libs\plugins\function.paginate_prev.php on line 58

Codes that are throwing errors.

```
if (SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex($_id) === false) {
    $smarty->trigger_error("paginate_prev: total was not set");
    return;        
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you're using SmartyPaginate1.6 and not the smart-3 ...  SmartyPaginate1.6 is a very obsolete script already, I recommend that you upgrade your template system to work with php7.

Comment: I am using latest Smarty. This is some error from plugin which is based on Smarty 1.6. There is no latest smarty paginate plugin available.

Comment: So the plugin is that it is obsolete/outdated. the solution is:
change technology or use an older version of PHP.

Comment: I was able to resolve most of the errors. I am having difficultly in converting one particular type of line into PHP 7 compatible code. I have updated description now.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved all the static errors. I did with following solutions.
Old Code

```
if (SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex($_id) === false) {
    $smarty->trigger_error("paginate_prev: total was not set");
    return;        
}
```

New Code

```
if ((new SmartyPaginate)->getCurrentIndex($_id) === false) {
    $smarty->trigger_error("paginate_next: total was not set");
    return;        
}
```